# Cannot open Tex file - Default encoding setting (UTF-8) not working

Tags: luatex, texmaker, unicode

Texmaker cannot open a .tex file. It says

> It seems that this file cannot be correctly decoded with the default encoding setting (UTF-8)

and asks me to choose an encoding option. ISO-8859-1 and ISO-8859-15 do not work.

The file was compiled with LuaLaTeX. I would like to edit this file, which encoding setting do you suggest?

Comment: (On Linux and(?) OSX:) What does `file` say? Also: can you run it through [iconv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv)? According to the Wikipedia page, `iconv` can also be made to work on Windows...

Comment: When you say it was *compiled* with LuaLaTeX, do you have the source or only the compiled version? You cannot recover the `.tex` source from the compiled output.

Comment: @cfr I have the .aux, .tex., .log, .out and the .pdf file

Comment: @jon I'm using Ubuntu. What format should I convert my file from?

Comment: Using a terminal, what does `file myfile.tex` say? (Assuming the problematic file is called "myfile.tex").  `iconv` lets you convert the file's encoding.  So something like `iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 < myfile.tex > newfile.tex` should convert it from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8.  If that doesn't work, I'd try to open the file with a real editor, like Emacs, and see what's going on.  (However, if you don't use Emacs normally, you might have to install it.)

Comment: The output is :`file CV.tex 
CV.tex: data`.
The iconv command generates a new file. But the file is full of unreadable characters.

Comment: When `file` command identifies the contents as "data" it basically means that the contents of that file do not follow any known pattern/format. Usually this happens when the file is encrypted or corrupt. In any case, it is not a valid `.tex` file. You have to get again the original from some other place/backup, since it looks like you have overwritten it with garbage somehow.